# Split a PDB text file into a number of files based on contents of each line

Tags: python

I am trying to extract NAD ligand id's chainwise from a [PDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Data_Bank) input file. I want to save output files as follows: if the input file is `1AHI.pbd` and contains four chains A, B, C and D, the output should be the separate files

```
1AHI_A.txt
1AHI_B.txt
1AHI_C.txt
1AHI_D.txt
```

My script below is not giving the expected output. May be some logical problem in the script. I am getting any error also.

```
from glob import glob

in_loc = 'C:/Users/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/'
out_loc = 'C:/Users/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/output/'

def test():
    fnames = glob(in_loc+'*.pdb')

    for each in fnames:
    # This is the new generated file out of input file (.txt).
        formatted_file = each.replace('pdb', 'txt')

        formatted_file = formatted_file.replace(in_loc, out_loc)

    # This is the input file
        in_f = open(each, 'r')

    # A new file to be opened.
        out_f = open(formatted_file, "w")

    # Filtering results from input file
        try:
            out_chain_list = filter_file(in_f)
            for each_line in out_chain_list:
                out_f.write(each_line)

        # Closing all the opened files.
            out_f.close()
            in_f.close()

        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception for file: ', each, '\n', e)
            out_f.close()
            in_f.close()


def filter_file(in_f):
    ligand_id = ['NAD']
    chain_ids = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    previous_chain_id = None
    chain_list = []
    out_chain_list = []

    for each in fnames:
        for line in map(str.rstrip, fnames):
            if line[:6] != "HETATM":
                continue
            chainID = line[21:22]
            ligandID = line[11:14].strip()

            if ligandID in ligandID and chain_id in chain_ids:

                if chain_id != previous_chain_id:
                    c_ls = []

                if c_ls:
                    out_file_name = in_f.name.replace(in_loc, out_loc)
                    out_file_name = out_file_name.replace('.pdb', '_'+previous_chain_id+'.txt')
                    out_file = open(out_file_name, "w")
                    for l in c_ls:
                    out_file.write(l)
                    out_file.close()

                chain_list.append(line)
                previous_chain_id = chain_id

                out_chain_list += c_ls

    return out_chain_list

test()
```

***Example:***

Input file: something like

```
HETATM15202  PA  NAD A 501      44.008 102.331   5.491  1.00 11.48           P  
HETATM15203  O1A NAD A 501      43.295 103.140   6.507  1.00 11.48           O  
HETATM15204  O2A NAD A 501      42.939 101.407   4.919  1.00 11.48           O  
HETATM15205  O5B NAD A 501      45.052 101.397   6.166  1.00 11.48           O  
HETATM15247  PA  NAD B 501      36.790 111.512  38.592  1.00 11.25           P  
HETATM15248  O1A NAD B 501      37.248 110.563  37.565  1.00 11.25           O  
HETATM15249  O2A NAD B 501      35.692 110.795  39.337  1.00 11.25           O  
HETATM15250  O5B NAD B 501      36.174 112.802  37.915  1.00 11.25           O  
HETATM15292  PA  NAD C 501     100.016 130.669  21.776  1.00 12.28           P  
HETATM15293  O1A NAD C 501      99.311 131.864  22.293  1.00 12.28           O  
HETATM15294  O2A NAD C 501     101.501 131.009  21.932  1.00 12.28           O  
HETATM15295  O5B NAD C 501      99.727 130.510  20.238  1.00 12.28           O  
HETATM15337  PA  NAD D 501      78.237 158.792  22.383  1.00 11.99           P  
HETATM15338  O1A NAD D 501      79.297 157.907  21.808  1.00 11.99           O  
HETATM15339  O2A NAD D 501      78.807 160.217  22.362  1.00 11.99           O  
HETATM15340  O5B NAD D 501      78.069 158.416  23.905  1.00 11.99           O
```

***Expected Output:***

1AHI_A.txt: A chain output (Output file)

```
HETATM15202  PA  NAD A 501      44.008 102.331   5.491  1.00 11.48           P  
HETATM15203  O1A NAD A 501      43.295 103.140   6.507  1.00 11.48           O  
HETATM15204  O2A NAD A 501      42.939 101.407   4.919  1.00 11.48           O  
HETATM15205  O5B NAD A 501      45.052 101.397   6.166  1.00 11.48           O
```

1AHI_B.txt: B chain output (Output file)

```
HETATM15247  PA  NAD B 501      36.790 111.512  38.592  1.00 11.25           P  
HETATM15248  O1A NAD B 501      37.248 110.563  37.565  1.00 11.25           O  
HETATM15249  O2A NAD B 501      35.692 110.795  39.337  1.00 11.25           O  
HETATM15250  O5B NAD B 501      36.174 112.802  37.915  1.00 11.25           O
```

1AHI_C.txt: C chain output (Output file)

```
HETATM15292  PA  NAD C 501     100.016 130.669  21.776  1.00 12.28           P  
HETATM15293  O1A NAD C 501      99.311 131.864  22.293  1.00 12.28           O  
HETATM15294  O2A NAD C 501     101.501 131.009  21.932  1.00 12.28           O  
HETATM15295  O5B NAD C 501      99.727 130.510  20.238  1.00 12.28           O
```

1AHI_D.txt: D chain output (Output file)

```
HETATM15337  PA  NAD D 501      78.237 158.792  22.383  1.00 11.99           P  
HETATM15338  O1A NAD D 501      79.297 157.907  21.808  1.00 11.99           O  
HETATM15339  O2A NAD D 501      78.807 160.217  22.362  1.00 11.99           O  
HETATM15340  O5B NAD D 501      78.069 158.416  23.905  1.00 11.99           O
```

I hope this will help you to understand.

I want to extract NAD (in third column of input file) and save output file separate file with chain wise.

Comment: Most people here won't be familiar with PDB files and ligands - can you show an example of the data to illustrate what you're trying to do? What is the expected output and what are you getting instead? Try to reduce this to the simplest example you can. Also it's not clear to me whether you are seeing error messages or not, but if so what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will read the PDB file specified by `fileName` and write an output file for each ligand ID found, containing the lines from the input file that begin with `HETATM` and contain `NAD` and a letter from `A` to `Z` in the specified locations:

```
import os

fileName = 'C:\\path\\to\\file.pdb'
baseName = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0] # get filename without extension

# Read the lines from the input file that have 'HETATM' and 'NAD' in the 
# correct positions into a list:
with open(fileName) as f:
    linesNAD = [li for li in f if li[0:6] == 'HETATM' and li[17:20] == 'NAD']

# Build a set of the chains found in the lines we have read in:
chains = {li[21] for li in linesNAD if li[21] in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'}

# For each chain, create an output file and write the lines for that chain:
for chain in chains:
    outfileName = baseName + '_' + chain + '.txt'
    with open(outfileName, 'w') as o:
        o.writelines([li for li in linesNAD if li[21] == chain])
```

You will be able to add to this if you want to process multiple input files, trap errors and so on. Note the use of list and set comprehensions which are often very concise ways of transforming or filtering a set of data. Look in the Python help if you need more detail on any of these constructions.

I've tested this on Python 3.5, but it should work in some earlier versions - I think set comprehensions are available in 2.7 but I'm not sure when the `with` structure was introduced. If it doesn't work in your version just open the files as you did in your original code (but don't forget to `close()` them afterwards!)

Comment: Thank you, I have 2000 input file. how can I use directory for input and output file? I new in python please suggest me

Comment: The way you have already done this in your code should work, I think. If it's giving you problems, try it out step by step, either at the Python command line or by writing a test script that e.g. just prints the path of each file instead of trying to process it. It's easy to try things out in Python and if you're new that's the best way to learn. If you get stuck again, search here for your specific problem (because it's probably been answered before) and if you can't find it, ask a new question about that specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but since I came across this, when I was searching for a solution to a problem that I have, I thought it would be better to share an easy solution. I know the question was to get the Python script working, but I thought one might find it useful if I leave this simple one-line solution (UNIX-based) here.

```
awk -F' ' '{print > "1AHI_"$5".txt"}' infile.pdb
```

Just insert a space after the string `HETATM` to separate the column 1 and 2 if there is no space due to increasing line numbers in the second column of the PDB file. All these could be done in one liner as shown below.

```
sed 's/HETATM/HETATM /1' infile.pdb | awk -F' ' '{print > "1AHI_"$5".txt"}'
```

`-F' '` would split columns on empty spaces and `$5` indicates `awk` to split the files on unique values in `$5`. You have to keep a space between single inverted commas of `-F' '`.